# Error while sharing Records with Apex sharing

Tags: trigger, apex-sharing

I have two objects, `pld` and `lead` (relationship is such that `lead` is a parent and `pld` is child).

When I'm changing the owner of pld objects then I want to share the lead with new owner of pld object, for which I have created Leadsharing and is updating the same in trigger. But,I'm getting following error:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

```
if(Trigger.oldmap.get(pld.id).ownerid != Trigger.newmap.get(pld.id).ownerid) {
    //Owner has changed
    LeadShare ldShare = new LeadShare();
    // Give Read write access to that user for this particular lead record.
    ldShare.LeadAccessLevel = 'edit' ;
    // Assign lead Id of lead record.
    ldShare.leadId = pld.Lead__c;
    // Assign user id to grant read write access to this particular lead record.
    ldShare.UserOrGroupId = pld.ownerid;
    System.debug('pld.ownerid update '+pld.ownerid);
    leadShareList.add( ldShare );
//sharestodelete.add(Trigger.oldmap.get(pld.)
}
if(!leadShareList.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        upsert leadShareList; 
    } catch(Exception e) {
      //trigger.new[0].Name.addError('Error::::::'+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Related Context: I have created a Leadsharing object for Lead.It contains list of all users to which the lead will be shared.The OWD for Lead is Private.But I'm performing the operation through System Admin.

Comment: Its difficult to suggest what's going wrong or where to look without looking whole code. List `leadShareList` has all fields populated?

Comment: At the beginning of the trigger I'm initializing the list as :                                list <LeadShare> leadShareList = new List<LeadShare>();    Only this much code is there for updating the leadShareList  in trigger.

Comment: Please check the OWD for both the objects , it looks like there is no share object available for LEAD

Comment: Hi Uday, there is a Leadshare object available for Lead,in which the users to which lead is shared are updated.OWD for both object pld and lead is private.But I'm performing the operation through SystemAdmin

Comment: hi @PankajAndhale, You dont have to update ldShare.leadId as it is already associated correctly. It is just the ownership you must update. Can you try it?

Comment: @PankajAndhale Hi, I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution to that?